# JavaScript src link

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

Boas,
tenho o seguinte código, em uma função `Javascript`,

```
function(){           
   var noDataIcon = document.createElement("img");

   noDataIcon.src = "~/Images/delete_database.png";

}
```

acontece de me deu erro no src, não consegue encontrar a imagem.

Como resolvo este problema?

Obrigado

Comment: Corrija o caminho da imagem o código está correto. :)

Comment: ja corrigi, ele está nesta pasta, mas continua a dar erro

Comment: "Images"... acho que o "I" é minúsculo.

Comment: Obrigado, já funcionou mas tive de retirar o ~

Answer (score 1):

> Como resolvo este problema?

Não usando esta notação:

```
"~/Images/delete_database.png";
```

Ela só é válida dentro do código do servidor. Não em código de cliente.

Utilize no lugar:

```
noDataIcon.src = "/Images/delete_database.png";
```

Se a aplicação estiver em um subdiretório, pode ser necessário ter que tratar o endereço.